# How to order SQL result by the earlier/older of two dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Assume a simple table with three field: An `user_id` and two dates `last_login` and `last_api_usage`.

I would like to find inactive users by ordering the the table by the earlier of the two dates. Example:

```
 user_id    | last_login    | last_api_usage
------------+---------------+----------------
 1          | 2020-06-01    | NULL
 2          | 2020-09-01    | 2020-03-01
 3          | 2020-05-01    | 2020-08-01

Result order: 2, 3, 1
```

User 2 is the most active because the although he did not use the API for a while the login was September. Next is user 3 due to the API usage in August.

Of course ordering the result by two dates is not problem (`...ORDER BY last_login, last_api_usage DESC`) but this would return the result `2, 1, 3` and is not what is intended.

How to order by the earlier/orlder of the two dates?

Comment: please also tag the dbms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `least` and `coalesce` function as follows:

```
ORDER BY least(last_login, coalesce(last_api_usage,last_login))
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. However, when one of the values is NULL than least will return NULL which leads to a wrong order. I could solve the problem by using `COALESCE` twice (arguments reversed): `ORDER BY least(coalesce(last_login,last_api_usage), coalesce(last_api_usage,last_login))`

Answer (score 0):

What' your RDBMS?

```sql
ORDER BY  ast_login, last_api_usage DESC  NULLS LAST
```

or use coalesce function

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OP you can `union all` to unpivot the column then order it.
for example:

```
select * from (
select user_id,use_date ,row_number()over(partition by user_id order by use_date desc) rn from (
select user_id, last_login as use_date
from [TABLE] 
union all
select user_id,last_api_usage
from [TABLE] 
) a ) b
where rn = 1
order by use_date
```

the logic is simple, combine both column into one column then filter the row with biggest `date`, in the following hyperlink I did not use proper date format for pseudo data but the idea is same.
here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4a58b52de644324b9958faff1e18fbb) for better examine.